# Are Hadith and Quran apps trustable?

Tags: quran, hadith, translation

These iOS/ Android apps that are available these days, like there isn't any authority backing them up or something. Sometimes there are even mistakes found in translation in some Hadith apps. I mean we have to just plain trust the devs of the apps right? I'm not saying this is a bad thing, since some of the applications are very usefull. It's just that I've found bugs in the apps a handful of times, and reviewers report mistranslations sometimes too. The devs write the whole thing down themselves, so how can we verify the legitimacy of the content in their apps?

Comment: notice, you will find misprints in books too.

Comment: @Kilise but the books (at least the most important ones ex sahih al bukhari) we buy are from trusted publishers example darussalam. But these apps, they are just from random devs. They may have serious mistakes and be missing content. Ofc that'd be okay for someone who's well versed with whatever the apps showing cuz they'd know if the app gets it wrong, but for people who are just getting into it and their primary source of those books are these apps, isn't that bad?

Comment: It depends on the developers of the apps. For example, the cross platform application named [Ayat][1] is created by a trustworthy source, a Saudi university.


  [1]: http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/ayat/?l=en